# Use const from another file in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ProgressBar from "./ProgressBar";

class Languages extends Component {
    state = {
        languages: [
            {id: 1, value: "XXX", xp: 1.5},
            {id: 2, value: "CCC", xp: 1},
            {id: 3, value: "AAA", xp: 2}
        ]
    }

    render() {
        let {languages} = this.state;
        const levels = ['Test', 'Bad', 'Sorry']

        return (
            <div className="languages">
                <ProgressBar
                    programming={languages}
                    className="languagesDisplay"
                    levels={levels}
                    title="Languages"
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Languages;
```

```
import React from 'react';

const ProgressBar = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={props.className}>
            <h3>{props.title}</h3>
            <div className="years">
                <span>Experiences</span>
                props.levels.map((level) => {
                    <span>level</span>
                })
            </div>
```

`<span>level</span>` return `props.levels.map((level) =>level)`

how can i display the `const ['Test', 'Bad', 'Sorry']` from Languages.js in a `<span>` in a different React file?

Comment: `<span>{level}</span>`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe `'level' is not defined  no-undef
`

Comment: `level` _is_ defined in what you've shown, as the parameter to the map callback, so if ESLint thinks otherwise please give a [mre] showing that.

Comment: you also need `{...}` around the whole `props.levels.map(...)` expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit after seeing your response above: If the issue is just that the above code isn't working, here are a couple of things to check.

Inside of `ProgressBar` you've got a couple of errors in your JSX. First, you need curly braces around your JavaScript interpolation and secondly, you're not **returning** anything in your .map() function. If you were using parentheses it would be an implicit return, but with the curly braces you need a return statement. Try this instead:

```js
import React from 'react';

const ProgressBar = (props) => {
    return ( <div className={props.className}>
        <h3> {props.title} </h3> 
        <div className ="years">
        <span> Experiences </span> 
        {props.levels.map((level) => {
            return (<span>{level}</span>)
          })
        } </div>
        )};
```

My initial answer, which still may be helpful for understanding what's going on:

It's not entirely clear what you want to do, but here are a couple of things that might be helpful.

What's happening in your code above is that the `levels` variable, which is an array of strings, is being passed down from the parent component `Languages` into the child component `ProgressBar` via the `props` object.

When `ProgressBar` is called inside of `Languages`, it's properties (or props) are set (`programming`, `className`, `levels`, `title`).
The `levels={levels}` part means that the prop `levels` on `ProgressBar` is being set to the variable `levels` (the array of strings).

Inside of `ProgressBar` all of those properties are accessible in the `props` object that's passed as an argument. That's why you're able to access that array of strings with `props.levels.map()` which will map the array of strings however you tell it to (in this case by printing each individual item within a `<span>` tag).

So, with that understanding of what's happening here, here are a couple of things you could do to access the `levels` variable elsewhere in another file.

If `levels` is a constant that you want to access in multiple places, you could move it outside of the body of your Languages component and export it to use it in other places.

That could look like:

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import ProgressBar from "./ProgressBar";

export const levels = ['Test', 'Bad', 'Sorry']

class Languages extends Component {
  state = {
    languages: [{
        id: 1,
        value: "XXX",
        xp: 1.5
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        value: "CCC",
        xp: 1
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        value: "AAA",
        xp: 2
      }
    ]
  }

  render() {
    let {
      languages
    } = this.state;


    return ( <
      div className = "languages" >
      <
      ProgressBar programming = {
        languages
      }
      className = "languagesDisplay"
      levels = {
        levels
      }
      title = "Languages" /
      >
      <
      /div>
    );
  }
}

export default Languages;
```

By exporting it from the top level, you could import it in another file exactly as it is.

```js
import { levels } from '/insert-first-file-location-here'
```

Another option is to pass the `levels` variable into another component as a prop. This way if `levels` gets changed at the top level, those changes will *drill down* into subsequent components.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ProgressBar from "./ProgressBar";

class Languages extends Component {
    state = {
        languages: [
            {id: 1, value: "XXX", xp: 1.5},
            {id: 2, value: "CCC", xp: 1},
            {id: 3, value: "AAA", xp: 2}
        ]
    }

    render() {
        let {languages} = this.state;
        const levels = ['Test', 'Bad', 'Sorry']

        return (
        <>
            <div className="languages">
                <ProgressBar
                    programming={languages}
                    className="languagesDisplay"
                    levels={levels}
                    title="Languages"
                />
            </div>
            <AnotherComponentThatUsesLevels
            levels={levels} />
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default Languages;
```

And then

```js
import React from 'react'

export const AnotherComponentThatUsesLevels (props) => {
return (
  <>
    {/* do something with levels here, maybe map them like before*/}
    {props.levels.map((level) => (<span>{level}</span>)}
  </>
  )
}
```

Does that help understand what's happening in the example and give you a couple of ways you could use that variable in another location?

Answer (score 1):

You need to export that certain constant from your file like that:

```
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';
import ProgressBar from "./ProgressBar";

export const levels = ['Test', 'Bad', 'Sorry']

class Languages extends Component {
    state = {
        languages: [{
                id: 1,
                value: "XXX",
                xp: 1.5
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                value: "CCC",
                xp: 1
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                value: "AAA",
                xp: 2
            }
        ]
    }

    render() {
        let {
            languages
        } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="languages">
                <ProgressBar
                    programming={languages}
                    className="languagesDisplay"
                    levels={levels}
                    title="Languages"
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Languages;
```

After it, you need to import it in the file where you want to access it:

```js
import {levels} from '/path/to/file';
```